# Create gitbook from github wiki pages

Tags: github, gitbook

I've a lot of documentation in github wiki. I would like organize it and create a book out of it. When ever I update the wiki, the book should be updated. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Gitbook. This service might help you. 
https://docs.gitbook.com/integrations/github/import-of-github-wikis

This service as far I read doesnt support github wiki directly.

However because github stores wiki as a seperate repository with reponame.wiki.git, you should be able to import this github repo into gitbook.

Comment: `However because github stores wiki as a seperate repository with reponame.wiki.git` That's interesting. I cannot find documentation about that. Do you have a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to do the same thing and sync our Gitlab-based wiki associated with a project to Gitbook to allow non technical team members without Gitlab access to also view and edit. To do this we:

1. Created a new Gitbook project/space for the wiki info and synchronized with with a new, empty Gitlab repo (since Gitbook does not allow sync directly with the wiki).
2. Added this new Gitlab repo as a second remote origin to the existing wiki repo and then pushed to this origin.
3. Now all we hav to do to keep things updated is to pull the latest from both possible remote sources and then merge and push them.