# What is the minimal step to create a Gitbook/pdf from GitWiki?

Tags: pdf, gitbook

Similar questions:
[Create gitbook from github wiki pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883964/create-gitbook-from-github-wiki-pages) , [How to import a markdown file from github into local gitbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248880/how-to-import-a-markdown-file-from-github-into-local-gitbook)

I need to read some documentation, and wish to save it all as PDFs (to read on my gigantor-ereader ;). Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955106/343215) to yet another similar question:

> This is exactly what GitBook is designed for ... It supports PDF output out of the box, as well as online publishing on
>   its own web platform.

I jumped in with both feet and installed:

- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm)
- [gitbook-cli](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/master/docs/setup.md)
- [ebook-convert](https://toolchain.gitbook.com/ebook.html)
- [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download)
- cloned the GitWiki that I want to convert to PDF

I did `$ gitbook init` in the local GitWiki. This gave me some of the basic files gitbook uses. I can serve a gitbook and generate a pdf, so I know my software installation was successful.

Unfortunately, the gitbook is empty. I can't find any instructions to add the md files, which are located in the same directory, to the gitbook I init'd.

What's the minimum steps necessary to gitbook a gitwiki?

Answer (score 1):

Ever since v2, Gitbook removed their official PDF export feature.  If you're using Gitbook V2, I've just released this CLI tool to create PDFs from your Gitbook. My company is already using to send books to print publishers.  It's free and open source, so please give it a test: https://www.forgebox.io/view/gitbook-exporter